# How to customize taxonomy edit page

Tags: taxonomy

I have custom taxonomy, how can I add new element to taxonomy edit page in admin panel. For example, I have album as taxonomy and song as post type, my issue is that I want to show all songs that belong to current album when I edit album. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that below code block, hope it will help you. Put it in your plugin or in theme's `functions.php`file and it'll work. I tested it with `category` taxonomy.

The code block-

```
// {$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields you should use
add_action( 'album_edit_form_fields', 'the_dramatist_add_custom_fields_to_taxonomy_edit_page', 10, 2 );
/**
 * The function for rendering posts related to the term.
 *
 * @param object $tag      Current taxonomy term object.
 * @param string $taxonomy Current taxonomy slug.
 */
function the_dramatist_add_custom_fields_to_taxonomy_edit_page( $tag, $taxonomy) {
    $songs_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_per_page' => -1,
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'album',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $taxonomy // slug of the term
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field term-description-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="description">Songs</label></th>
        <td>
            <table>
                <?php
                if( $songs_query->have_posts() ):
                    while( $songs_query->have_posts() ): $songs_query->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h3><?php the_title()?></h3>
                                <p><?php the_content()?></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```